# How do I specify troff man page generation & installation using CMake?

Tags: cmake, manpage

I'm trying to switch a Makefile-based build to using CMake. I'm ok with specifying the build of the app itself, but - there's also a man (manual) page, in TROFF format.

- How do I tell CMake to process it into an installable form (e.g. processing if necessary, compression), alongside the building of the executable?
- How do I get CMake to install it to an appropriate location?

Comment: what exactly does "installable form" mean? what needs to happen to do that processing? can you elaborate on what logic you want to happen for install location (I.e. elaborate on what "appropriate location" means?) Is there any particular reason why GNUInstallDir's `MANDIR`, `DOCDIR`, or `INFODIR` don't work for you? Or did you just not know about them?

Comment: @starball: 1. See edit. 2. Ok, there's a `MANDIR`, but what command do I issue which uses it?

Comment: How to process troff into installable form? What command exactly do you want to execute? What is the appropriate location of that executable? /usr/bin?

Comment: 1) so you don't know what processing you want to do with it? Is there a particular reason you think you might need compression? is compression of docs conventional for installation purposes? 2) https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#files

Comment: @starball: 1. I've never installed man pages before, so, yes, I don't know. I specifically don't know what one does with TROFF files. Yes, there is a particular reason: On my system, most man pages are gzipped. 2. That page doesn't deal with man files.

Comment: @KamilCuk : "How to process" <- I don't know. I have a TROFF file, I've not handled those before. Maybe I only need to compress it. "What command exactly" <- Again, don't know. Whatever one usually does with TROFFs for man pages. "location of that executable" <- depends on the install prefix. If you like, let's assume it's `/opt/foo/bin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compress something, use [the `file(ARCHIVE_CREATE ...)` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#archiving).

To install something that's intended to be a manpage, use [the `install(FILES ...)` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#files) and use [`CMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html#result-variables) in the `DESTINATION` argument.

Comment: So, there are no fancier man-specific commands, I take it?

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike in the latest CMake (3.27) at the time of this writing, as far as I know, without pulling in custom modules, no.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @starball's answer:

There is currently no "hand-holding" specialty mechanism for handling manual files, so you need to take care of archive compression. No preliminary processing of the TROFF file is necessary.

Suppose your program name is `foo` and the TROFF file's relative path in the repository is `doc/foo.1`.

First, increase your CMake version dependency to 3.18, to have access to the [`file(ARCHIVE_CREATE)` command variant](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#archiving).

Now, in your `CMakeLists.txt`, add the following lines:

```cmake
include(GNUInstallDirs)
file(ARCHIVE_CREATE OUTPUT foo.1.gz PATHS doc/foo.1 FORMAT raw COMPRESSION GZip)
install(FILES foo.1.gz DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR}")
```

(the `GNUINstallDirs` module is what defines the `_MANDIR` install path.)